# Proof of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(x-b)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find out under what conditions the equality $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(x-b)^n$ holds.

Now I'm thinking about the following conditions:

1. $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^\infty$ on an open set $U$.
2. $a\in U, b\in U$

I expect the equality to be true, but I can't prove it.

My attempt:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-b+b-a)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(x-b)^k(b-a)^{n-k}\\
&=^{?}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n+k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^k\right)(x-b)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(x-b)^n
\end{aligned}$$

My attempt to prove $=^?$:

Let
$$\begin{aligned}
X&=x-b,\\
Y&=b-a,\\
c_n&=f^{(n)}(a),\\
d_n&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_{n+k}}{k!}Y^k
\end{aligned}$$

The problem is to prove

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!}(X+Y)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}d_nX^n$$

under the condition that the left-hand side and $d_n$ converge.

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_k}{k!}(X+Y)^k$, $S=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$. For any positive number $ε$, there is $N$ that satisfies $m\geq N\Rightarrow|S-S_m|<\frac{ε}{3}$.

For $k=1, 2, ..., n$, there is $N_k$ that satisfies $m\geq N_k\Rightarrow |d_k-\sum_{i=0}^m\frac{c_{k+i}}{i!}Y^i|<\frac{ε}{3(n+1)}\frac{k!}{|X|^k}$. Let $M=\max_{k=1, ..., n} N_k+n$.

Then,

$$\left|S-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}d_kX^k\right| \leq |S-S_M|+\left|S_M-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}d_kX^k\right|$$

Because $S_M
=\sum_{i=0}^M\frac{c_i}{i!}\sum_{k=0}^i\binom{i}{k}X^kY^{i-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^M\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{(i+k)!}\binom{i+k}{k}Y^i\right)X^k
=\sum_{k=0}^M\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{i!}Y^i\right)X^k$,

$$\begin{aligned}
\left|S_M-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}d_kX^k\right|
&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{X^k}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{i!}Y^i-d_k\right) +\sum_{k=n+1}^M\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{i!}Y^i\right)X^k\right|\\
&< \frac{ε}{3}+\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^M\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{i!}Y^i\right)X^k\right|
\end{aligned}$$

Thus,

$$\left|S-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}d_kX^k\right|<\frac{2ε}{3}+\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^M\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{M-k} \frac{c_{i+k}}{i!}Y^i\right)X^k\right|$$

I can't go any further from here.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic then both sides are equal to $f(x)$ so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Those two conditions are too weak. You can easily create an infinitely differentiable function $f$ with $f \equiv 0$ near a neighbor of $a$ and $f \equiv 1$ near a neighbor of $b$.

Comment: They are not even guaranteed to converge on the same domain, how could you compare them for equality?

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand that the equation does not hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation does not hold. We can create an infinitely differentiable function $$ with $≡0$ near a neighbor of $$ and $≡1$ near a neighbor of $$.